# How to search and replace multiple values in an array using jq?

Tags: jq

In the following json file,

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "phone": "1234"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane",
            "phone": "5678"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update both phone numbers based on the name and store the whole json in a new file.

I tried stuff like:

```
jq '.contacts[] | select(.name == "John") | .phone = "4321"' < contacts.json >updated_contacts.json
```

But then I don't know how to go back to the parent node and change Jane's one, nor retrieve the whole json.

I tried to store to root node in a variable with `as`, but it keeps unchanged.

As a temporary workaround I'm just doing this:

```
jq '.contacts[0].number = "4321" | .contacts[1].number = "4321"' < contacts.json >updated_contacts.json
```

But I should not rely on array indexes, but names, as the original json may change.

Any idea how could I do it using jq command?

Comment: Are you always changing John's and Jane's numbers to the same number? What would you want to input to this, a list of names and one list of corresponding numbers to change to, or do you want to input (an array of) JSON objects like `{ name: "John", phone: "4321" }`, so that one could find the correct name and new number from that?  Would it be ok to do this in a simple loop, processing one entry at a time, or would you want to insist on doing everything in _one_ invocation of `jq`?

Comment: I don't need to replace n values, just these 2 ones, but the contacts array could contain more elements, and they could be in any order. New phone numbers are mapped with --arg parameter, but I omited it for simplicity. Chaining 2 jq invocations should not be a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change one entry, make sure that you use `|=` and that the left hand side of that update operator is a path in the *original* document:

```bsh
jq --arg name John --arg phone 4321 \
    '( .contacts[] | select(.name == $name) ).phone |= $phone' file
```

You can't use `.contacts[] | select(.name == "John") | .phone |= ...` since the `select()` actually extracts a set of elements from the `contacts` array.  You would therefore only change the elements that you extract, separately from the main part of the document.

Notice the difference in

```
( ... | select(...) ).phone |= ...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
path in original document
```

which works, and

```bsh
... | select(...) | .phone |= ...
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
      extracted bits
```

which doesn't work.

---

Using a loop for more than one entry, assuming e.g. `bash`:

```bsh
names=( John Jane )
phones=( 4321 4321 )

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

for i in "${!names[@]}"; do
    name=${names[i]}
    phone=${phones[i]}

    jq --arg name "$name" --arg phone "$phone" \
        '( .contacts[] | select(.name == $name) ).phone |= $phone' file >"$tmpfile"
    mv -- "$tmpfile" file
done
```

That is, I put the names in one array and the new numbers in another, then loop over the indexes and update `file` for each entry that needs changing, using a temporary file an intermediate storage.

Or, with an associative array:

```bsh
declare -A lookup

lookup=( [John]=4321 [Jane]=4321 )

for name in "${!lookup[@]}"; do
    phone=${lookup[$name]}

    # jq as above
done
```

---

Assuming you have some JSON input document with the new phone numbers, such as

```json
{
   "John": 1234,
   "Jane": 5678
}
```

which you can create using

```bsh
jo John=1234 Jane=5678
```

Then you can update the numbers in a single `jq` invocation:

```bsh
jo John=1234 Jane=5678 |
jq --slurpfile new /dev/stdin \
    '.contacts |= map(.phone = ($new[][.name] // .phone))' file
```

This reads our input JSON with the new numbers inte a structure, `$new`, that looks like

```json
[
  {
    "John": 1234,
    "Jane": 5678
  }
]
```

This is used in the `map()` call to change the phone numbers of any contact that is listed.  The `// .phone` makes sure that if the name isn't listed, the phone number stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kusalananda's answer, if you only want to search and replace 2 values you can do somethig like this in one jq invocation:

```
jq '( .contacts[] | select(.name == "John") ).phone |= "4321" | 
    ( .contacts[] | select(.name == "Jane") ).phone |= "8765"' \
    contacts.json
```

Or this way chaining 2 jq invocations:

```
cat contacts.json | \
jq '( .contacts[] | select(.name == "John") ).phone |= "4321"' | \
jq '( .contacts[] | select(.name == "Jane") ).phone |= "8765"'
```